# Where to use StreamReader.DiscardBufferedData()?

Tags: c#, streamreader

I have the following code:

```
StreamReader StreamReader = new StreamReader("File.txt");
string Line = "";

while((Line = StreamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string Value = Line.Trim();
    string Value2 = StreamReader.ReadLine();
    int CursorValue = StreamReader.BaseStream.Position;

    if(Condition)
    {
        StreamReader.BaseStream.Position = SOMETHING_ELSE;
        Console.WriteLine(StreamReader.ReadLine());
    }

    StreamReader.BaseStream.Position = CursorValue;
}
```

Can anybody tell me where I am supposed to use `StreamReader.DiscardBufferedData()` here?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: What are you trying to do ? And what is wrong with [File.ReadAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

Comment: If only they gave an example of usage on the documentation page for [`DiscardBufferedData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.discardbuffereddata(v=vs.110).aspx). Oh wait, they do.

Comment: The Position property you get after calling ReadLine() is a random value.  Calling DiscardBufferedData is no workaround for that.

Comment: That's "[How Do I Write a Good Title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title)", by the way.

Comment: @SonerGönül maybe it worth removing tags from question title? :)

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy: yeah, but the title is so bad that this would leave "StreamReader".

Comment: Probably an empty title in this case..

Comment: @JohnSaunders [tag:StreamReader] is also a tag :)

Comment: I have edited the title in the spirit of the original.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Definitly which John already did it `:)`

Comment: Don't be too harsh, we all have seen worse here on SO. For that code it is a valid question. Not saying that the actual question is one to present as example for other people, but that's another story.

--edit I see the title was already edited, not sure what it was so neglect this comment :).

Comment: Don't forget to call Dispose/wrap it in a using statement after using the StreamReader.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From MSDN:

> Use the DiscardBufferedData method to reset the internal buffer for the StreamReader object. You need to call this method only when the position of the internal buffer and the BaseStream do not match.

So a little example:

```
Stream s = new MemoryStream();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s);
// Read things here.
s.Position = 10;
sr.DiscardBufferedData();        // reader now reading from position 0
sr.BaseStream.Seek(10, SeekOrigin.Begin); // Reader now reading from location 10.
```

In your case:

```
StreamReader.BaseStream.Position = SOMETHING_ELSE;
sr.DiscardBufferedData();
StreamReader.BaseStream.Seek(SOMETHING_ELSE, SeekOrigin.Begin);
Console.WriteLine(StreamReader.ReadLine());
```

and dont forget to set back again at:

```
StreamReader.BaseStream.Position = CursorValue;
sr.DiscardBufferedData();
StreamReader.BaseStream.Seek(CursorValue, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

Answer (score 1):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.discardbuffereddata%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> **Use the DiscardBufferedData method to reset the internal buffer for
>   the StreamReader object.** You need to call this method only when the
>   position of the internal buffer and the BaseStream do not match. These
>   positions can become mismatched when you read data into the buffer and
>   then seek a new position in the underlying stream. This method slows
>   performance and should be used only when absolutely necessary, such as
>   when you want to read a portion of the contents of a StreamReader
>   object more than once. For a list of common I/O tasks, see Common I/O
>   Tasks.