# Seek through FileStream then using StreamReader to read from there

Tags: c#, filestream, streamreader

So I want to be able to seek to a point in a fileStream, then read forward using a StreamReader. Then seek forward again, and use the StreamReader to read another chunk of data.

```
const int BufferSize = 4096;
var buffer = new char[BufferSize];

var endpoints = new List<long>();

using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{ 
    var fileLength = fileStream.Length;

    var seekPositionCount = fileLength / concurrentReads;

    long currentOffset = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < concurrentReads; i++)
    {
        var seekPosition = seekPositionCount + currentOffset;

        // seek the file forward
        fileStream.Seek(seekPosition, SeekOrigin.Current);

        // setting true at the end is very important, keeps the underlying fileStream open.
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8, true, BufferSize, true))
        {
            // this also seeks the file forward the amount in the buffer...
            int bytesRead;
            var totalBytesRead = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = await streamReader.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                totalBytesRead += bytesRead;

                var found = false;

                var gotR = false;

                for (var j = 0; j < buffer.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (buffer[j] == '\r')
                    {
                        gotR = true;
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (buffer[j] == '\n' && gotR)
                    {
                        // so we add the total bytes read, minus the current buffer amount read, then add how far into the buffer we actually read.
                        seekPosition += totalBytesRead - BufferSize + j;
                        endpoints.Add(seekPosition);
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (found) break;
            }
        }
        
        // we need to seek to the position we got to in the StreamReader (but not going by how much was read).
        fileStream.Seek(seekPosition, SeekOrigin.Current);

        currentOffset += seekPosition;
    }
}

return endpoints;
```

However, I get to two entries in `endpoints` and it exits out.

```
(bytesRead = await streamReader.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0
```

The arguments you pass to `ReadAsync` I thought are solely to do with the buffer, so the `index` argument I thought was to say, fill the `buffer` at `index`.

I can't make out from [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs,22c74cf81f5f1e56) how this value is used.

I assumed (and can't find the evidence to back up) that, when you opened a `StreamReader` it uses the underlying `Stream` as it's guide, so when you ask to read some bytes, it will start from the position the underlying `Stream` is at...

But the results of what I'm doing aren't showing that, they seem to be showing that the `StreamReader` is starting at the beginning of the `Stream` each time - however, I can't find the evidence to support that is how it does it either...

### Seeking

Is my understanding of seeking correct, in the sense that if I call seek

```
fileStream.Seek(seekPosition, SeekOrigin.Current);
```

If the file is at `300`, I want to seek to `600`, the above variable `seekPosition` should be `600`??

ReferenceSource would say otherwise:

```
else if (origin == SeekOrigin.Current) {
    // Don't call FlushRead here, which would have caused an infinite
    // loop.  Simply adjust the seek origin.  This isn't necessary
    // if we're seeking relative to the beginning or end of the stream.
    offset -= (_readLen - _readPos);
}
```

Comment: StreamReader keeps its own buffer, you'll have to call its DiscardBufferedData() method to force it to re-synchronize with the FileStream.

Comment: Where abouts, after each read?

Comment: @HansPassant ahh the source codes says

Comment: @HansPassant it is interesting because it says if you need to re-read, but if you're constantly seeking forward, why would it be inefficient...

Comment: [Found similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21163162/where-to-use-streamreader-discardbuffereddata)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to Hans Passant, I have got the answer:

```
var buffer = new char[BufferSize];

var endpoints = new List<long>();

using (var fileStream = this.CreateMultipleReadAccessFileStream(fileName))
{
    var fileLength = fileStream.Length;

    var seekPositionCount = fileLength / concurrentReads;

    long currentOffset = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < concurrentReads; i++)
    {
        var seekPosition = seekPositionCount + currentOffset;

        // seek the file forward
        // fileStream.Seek(seekPosition, SeekOrigin.Current);

        // setting true at the end is very important, keeps the underlying fileStream open.
        using (var streamReader = this.CreateTemporaryStreamReader(fileStream))
        {
            // this is poor on performance, hence why you split the file here and read in new threads.
            streamReader.DiscardBufferedData();
            // you have to advance the fileStream here, because of the previous line
            streamReader.BaseStream.Seek(seekPosition, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            // this also seeks the file forward the amount in the buffer...
            int bytesRead;
            var totalBytesRead = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = await streamReader.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                totalBytesRead += bytesRead;

                var found = false;

                var gotR = false;

                for (var j = 0; j < buffer.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (buffer[j] == '\r')
                    {
                        gotR = true;
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (buffer[j] == '\n' && gotR)
                    {
                        // so we add the total bytes read, minus the current buffer amount read, then add how far into the buffer we actually read.
                        seekPosition += totalBytesRead - BufferSize + j;
                        endpoints.Add(seekPosition);
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    // if we have found new line then move the position to 
                }

                if (found) break;
            }
        }

        currentOffset = seekPosition;
    }
}

return endpoints;
```

Note the new part, rather than doing this *twice*:

```
fileStream.Seek(seekPosition, SeekOrigin.Current);
```

I now use `SeekOrigin.Begin` and use the `StreamReader` to progress the underlying base stream:

```
// this is poor on performance, hence why you split the file here and read in new threads.
streamReader.DiscardBufferedData();
// you have to advance the fileStream here, because of the previous line
streamReader.BaseStream.Seek(seekPosition, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

The `DiscardBufferedData` will mean that I'm always using the underlying stream position.